# Find the radius of the path of an electron in a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

In a question I am asked to find the radius of the circular path that an electron follows in a magnetic field.

The field strength is $B=10^{-5}T$ along the positive y axis, the velocity of the electron is $v=10^{7}m/s$ along the positive x axis.

I have already worked out that the strength of the force acting on the electron is $1.602*10^{-17}N$ along the negative z axis.

I am trying to use the equation $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$ with $m=9.1083*10^{-31}kg$ and $q=1.602*10^{-19}C$

but I am being told that the answer using these numbers is incorrect?

Id appreciate any help as I'm sure i must be making a silly mistake somewhere...

Comment: It'll be a very minor effect, but $v = 10^7 ms^{-1}$ is getting close to the speed of light. If this is part of a special relativity course, it's possible you're supposed to be doing this relativistically.

Comment: The relativistic correction is very small at $\frac{c}{30}$.  Perhaps that is what you needed to find out?

Comment: If special relativity is the real issue with the answers, then OP will need to transform the EM tensor also.  I doubt that SR is important in this problem.  A force of $10^{17}N$ shows that there is a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: hi, its physics 1101, the first semester, first year course, so im hoping SR isnt the problem, and I did write the force incorrectly in my question, in my actual answer it was e-17.

Answer (score 1):

The power in the value of force is not right. There is a negative sign there.

$F=1.602*10^{-17}$N

$m=9.1083*10^{-31}$kg  is not the right way to use here. The particle is moving close to the speed of light. The value of m you used here is the rest mass of electron. You need to apply the relativistic mass here given by the formula

$m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

where $m_0$ is the rest mas of electron  ($9.1083*10^{-31}$kg)

v the velocity of electron

c the velocity of light in vacuum    ($3*10^{8} m/s$)

Try applying these corrections

Comment: What about Lorentz transforming the B-field, too?

Comment: I don't know whether the question is that level. May be this is a question at or below undergraduate level

Comment: If the speed is such that the momentum needs transforming then one should check that the EM fields should be, too. The $\gamma$ is only ~1801/1800, so I don't think that's important below  a senior level university course.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to show your working and state what answer you got using these numbers.  Otherwise we have no idea if you have made a mistake in your calculation or the 'official' answer is incorrect.  As Unnikrishnan points out, it is probably because you used an incorrect value for F, which is too big by many orders of magnitude for the force on an electron.